# How does the group in regular expression work when there is only one group?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I did the following:

```
a = re.compile("(ab*?)")
b = a.search("abbbbbbb")
```

The following gave me the answer 'a':

```
b.group(0)
```

Surprisingly, this also gave me the answer 'a':

```
b.group(1)
```

I get a tuple containing only ('a',) when I do this:

```
b.groups()
```

If there is only one group, why did it give repeated values for indices 0 and 1? Shouldn't it have raised an IndexError at 1?

Comment: Not sure how this is possible, considering the documentation for `group()` states `If a group number is negative or larger than the number of groups defined in the pattern, an IndexError exception is raised.`

Comment: Why don't you try it and see it for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`help(b.group)`

```
Help on built-in function group:

group(...) method of _sre.SRE_Match instance
    group([group1, ...]) -> str or tuple.
    Return subgroup(s) of the match by indices or names.
    For 0 returns the entire match.
```

Regular expressions start numbering the capture groups at 1. Trying to access group 0 will give you the entire match (all groups), but since the expression has only one group the outputs are the same.

Example:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(first) (second)")
>>> results = regex.search("first second")
>>> results.group(1)
'first'
>>> results.group(2)
'second'
>>> results.group(0)
'first second'
```

Comment: Could you give one example to elaborate?

Comment: @MithilBhoras I added an example to my answer